# Prove $ \frac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta} - \frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta} = 2\cot \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove $$ \frac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta} - \frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta} = 2\cot \theta$$

So I started by combining the two fractions, which gave me:
$$ \frac{\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta) - \sin\theta(1-\cos\theta)}{(1-\cos\theta)(1+\cos\theta)}  = \frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{1-\cos^2\theta} = \frac{\sin2\theta}{1-\cos^2\theta}$$
I wasn't sure where to go from here considering I'm aiming for $2\cos\theta / \sin\theta$

Comment: Just use $\sin(2\theta) = 2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)$ and $1-\cos^2(\theta) = \sin^2(\theta)$.

Comment: Why are you writing $\sin2\theta$ instead of simply changing $1-\cos^2\theta=\sin^2\theta$ and simplify?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{1-\cos^2\theta} =\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta} = \frac{2\cos\theta}{\sin \theta} =  2\cot \theta$$

Comment: @H.Linkhorn, Maria Mazur has provided the answer. I wonder why some people down voted it! I up voted! Note that the LHS in Maria's answer is the simplification (just cross multiplication) of the LHS in your original question.

Answer (score 2):

It's $$\frac{\sin2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}=\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}=\frac{2\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=2\cot\theta.$$

Comment: Where does that identity come from?

Comment: @H.Linkhorn I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

As $\sin^2t=1-\cos^2t=(1-?)(1+?)$

$$\dfrac{\sin t}{1\pm\cos t}=\dfrac{1\mp \cos t}{\sin t}$$